# How can I create a file to fill up the disk via cmd?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe

I want to fill up the disk for a test which requires the disk storage to be full. For this, I found that I could use the command line with the following command: `fsutil file createnew <filename> <filesize in bytes>`. Combined with `fsutil volume diskfree <disk>` to find out how much space is currently available this is fine so far and it works for the use case.

Now I have the question, can I somehow combine these commands, so that it can be "automated" in a way, that I don't have to manually check for the free storage and create the file accordingly?

In short, can somehow combine the output from `fsutil volume diskfree` with the input of `fsutil file createnew` to create a file that fills up the disk? Does a "one-liner" solution in cmd (or alternatively power shell) exist for this task?

OS in question is Win10 Enterprise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following powershell command get the free space of the disk using WMI then use fsutil to create the newfile. Don't forget to change the volume name if it's necessary.

```
$space = $(get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk | where-object -Property DeviceID -EQ "C:" | select -ExpandProperty FreeSpace) ; fsutil file createNew yourFileName $space
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Works flawlessly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's worth noting that you'll get a `Not enough space` error in `fsutil` if you're filling a FAT32 drive and `$space` is above 4 GB (due to the max file size allowed).

Answer (score 1):

It is really easy , you can do using this command on cmd:

```
for /F %C in ('wmic logicaldisk C: Get FreeSpace ^| find /V "FreeSpace" ^|find /I " "') do fsutil file createnew q %C
```

Creates a file named **q** in the current cmd directory (default C:\Windows\system32), file size equal to free space of drive **C:**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to get the free space of the C:\ drive and then send the output to a file named **freespace.txt**  after that it uses FOR to convert D into a variable and then uses fsutil to create a file named **spacefiller** that fills up the hard drive. the **freespace.txt** and **spacefiller** can be changed to anything you want, as long as you change them in both of the spots.

```
WMIC LOGICALDISK C: GET FreeSpace | find /V "FreeSpace" > freespace.txt & for /f %L in (freespace.txt) do fsutil file CreateNew spacefiller %L
```